# How to list the bean's properties

Tags: java

I have a bean, is there a way to list bean's all properties without list one by one?

Some beans overide the ToString() method which is handy. Howvere the beans which does not override this method?

Comment: toString() is a method. Not a bean property. What exactly do you want to do? Have you browsed the java.lang.Class javadoc?

Comment: If this is inside Eclipse and you are happy with generated code, then consider just letting Eclipse autogenerate it.  Look in the Right-Click->Source menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection. Take declared fields from class, it they are private check if they have setters and getters (remember boolean getter is "isProperty")

Code can look like this:

```
List<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>();
Class<?> cl = MyBean.class;

// check all declared fields
for (Field field : cl.getDeclaredFields()) {

    // if field is private then look for setters/getters
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {

        // changing 1st letter to upper case
        String name = field.getName();
        String upperCaseName = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + name.substring(1);
        // and have getter and setter
        try {
            String simpleType = field.getType().getSimpleName();
            //for boolean property methods should be isProperty and setProperty(propertyType)
            if (simpleType.equals("Boolean") || simpleType.equals("boolean")) {
                if ((cl.getDeclaredMethod("is" + upperCaseName) != null)
                        && (cl.getDeclaredMethod("set" + upperCaseName,
                                field.getType()) != null)) {
                    properties.add(name);
                }
            } 
            //for not boolean property methods should be getProperty and setProperty(propertyType)
            else {
                if ((cl.getDeclaredMethod("get" + upperCaseName) != null)
                        && (cl.getDeclaredMethod("set" + upperCaseName,
                                field.getType()) != null)) {
                    properties.add(name);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            // if there is no method nothing bad will happen
        }
    }
}
for (String property:properties)
    System.out.println(property);
```

Comment: That looks like a lot of code.  Any way to simplify the process?

Comment: There are few classes in `java.bean` package which could simplify it, but I am not sure if you want to use them. For instance what properties do you find in `class Person{private int height; public getHeight(){..} public setHeight(int h){..} boolean isTall(){return height>180;} }`? If we use my approach you will only get only `height`, but if you will use these helper classes you will get `height` `tall` but also `class` since every class has `getClass()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in parsing all properties of the Bean after deserialization from GSON.  This is for my Android app.

Comment: "I am interested in parsing all properties" but what do you mean by *property*? Can existence of `getFoo()` or `setFoo(f)` methods mean that there is `foo` property even if there is no `private someType foo` field in your class?

Comment: I am interested in transient properties (non-private) only. And with GSON + Retrofit on Android, setters are implicit.

Comment: It seems that your requirements are little different than one from this question. Consider creating separate question in which you will explain what you want to achieve (examples are welcome) and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) via BeanIntrospection as follows:

```
Object o = new MyBean();
try {
    BeanInfo bi = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyBean.class);
    PropertyDescriptor[] pds = bi.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (int i=0; i<pds.length; i++) {
        // Get property name
        String propName = pds[i].getName();

        // Get the value of prop1
        Expression expr = new Expression(o, "getProp1", new Object[0]);
        expr.execute();
        String s = (String)expr.getValue();
    }
    // class, prop1, prop2, PROP3
} catch (java.beans.IntrospectionException e) {
}
```

Or you can go with reflection method using one of the following approaches:

1. Get all no-parameter getXXX() methods through getDeclaredMethods and traverse them
2. Get all fields using getDeclaredFields() and traverse them (Not compliant with Bean spec, if you care about it)

Answer (score 4):

see apache commons lang - [ReflectionToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html)

Comment: Updated link: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html), a class that may accompany a bean class, without that the bean class need to be altered. It is used in many GUI builders to show properties of a bean, but has its non-GUI uses too.